# OS X 10.6でリソースフォークの情報を読み込む方法

Tags: objective-c, c++

現在開発中のプログラムにおいて、SoundDesigner2のファイル「.sd2」を読み込む必要があります。

その中で、リソースフォークに書かれているデータを読み込むために、
以前は`TextUtils.h`の`StringHandle GetString(short stringID)`を利用していましたが、10.5.sdk からDeprecated になっています。

ヘッダファイルを見ると、以下のような記述があるのですが、CFBundleCopyLocalizedString の使い方がよく分かりません。

```
 *  Deprecated:
 *    use CFBundleCopyLocalizedString instead.
```

どなたか、CFBundleCopyLocalizedString の使い方、もしくは、
どんな方法でも構いませんので「.sd2」ファイルのリソースフォークを読み込む方法をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、教えて頂けないでしょうか。

Comment: これは `C++` タグが付いているべき質問なのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

構造が分かっているのなら「SplitForks」コマンドでデータフォークに変換して("._"+ファイル名)から普通に読み込むとか？